# Data fragmentation in mongo collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a lot of updates in one mongo collection and assume huge fragmentation on file system after that. My main concern that collection will constantly grow on file system without valuable growing of data in collection.

Could you please confirm or refute my concern?

Comment: Have you tried repairing it and measuring filesize change?

Comment: Yes, and didn't get valuable difference. But for me is more interesting theoretical possibility.

Comment: I'd recommend reading this link aslo - http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/17174/mongo-collection-size-is-larger-than-storagesize/18249#18249. It should help your understanding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what kind of updates you're making. If these updates grow your document (array push or similar), then yes, you will have some fragmentation. In-place updates ($inc) don't cause document to be moved (no fragmentation).

By the way, it's not fragmentation per se, but rather some wasted space. That is, if document is moved to a new location, its old location won't be reused.

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Isn't there ANY way to make the system reuse the location of the old data. I cannot take the db offline though. Basically something like the repair command but document by document and online..

Comment: You can use replica sets. Take a slave offline, defragment, bring it back online, wait for it to sync, make it a new master, repeat.

Comment: Thanks. That is probably the best approach for now - till 10gen implements automatic defragmentation (kinda like NTFS).