# How to model daily deltas in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, time-series, nosql

I have some stock price data I want to model in MongoDB. Logically each stock price has a date, stock name, and price associated with it. One of the main aims of the application is to model the daily change in stock price.

I have two questions associated with this problem.

1) What would be the best way to model this sort of data in MongoDB given the sort of queries I'll be running on it.

UPDATE!!! I've done a bit of experimentation and have decided to denormalise the data and make sure I have appropriate column indexes. I didn't actually see any performance difference in nesting the data for the type of queries I was running, and it complicated the process of writing aggregation routines. Thanks for the advice Raxit!

2) Given 1) What is the best way to write these daily change style queries in MongoDB?

---

So after now I have one document per date and stock.

```
{
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-01",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-02",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Bob",
     "date":"2012-12-03",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Ted",
     "date":"2012-12-01",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Ted",
     "date":"2012-12-02",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    {"stock":"Ted",
     "date":"2012-12-03",
     "price":99.99                         
    },
    .
    .
    .


}
```

My thoughts on 2:

I want to generate reports that display the daily change in stock prices. Given Document size limitations I may need to split this up to be the deltas per stock and per year or something but that is more of an implementation detail. Essentially I want to output documents of the form:

```
{
 {"stock":"Bob",
          "prices": {[{"fromDate":"2012-12-01","toDate":"2012-12-02","delta":-1.0},
                     {"fromDate":"2012-12-02","toDate":"2012-12-03","delta":-1.0},
                     .
                     .
                     .]}
 },
 {"stock":"Ted",
          "prices": {[{"fromDate":"2012-12-01","toDate":"2012-12-02","delta":1.0},
                     {"fromDate":"2012-12-02","toDate":"2012-12-03","delta":1.0},
                     .
                     .
                     .]}
 },
 .
 .
 .
}
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to return this data on an adhoc basis. I'm pretty sure this could be done using map-reduce, but I was wondering whether there was a way to do this using the new aggregation framework? Before I started researching mongodb I'd assumed modelling change in this way would be a faily common use case but so far I've not come across anything quite like it.

Any advice you can give would be extremely useful. I'll update the post as my own research progresses.

Thanks,

Matt.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in above two case your data inside embedded doc is changed (added)!

what about simple structure 
{stockname:'bob',date:date1,price:200}
{stockname:'bob',date:date2,price:220}
etc?

or even

{stockname:'bob',date:date2,price:200, lastdate:date1,pricedelta:(price2-price1)}

Comment: Is there a problem inherent to adding to an embedded collection in mongodb? You are quite correct that I'd need to update the prices collection every time new data came in. Write performance is not a priority in this application however as I'm planning on batch inserting all of particular days stock data in in one go. The main focus is on read performance which is why I was thinking of embedding.

Comment: Go with what i suggested with proper index.

Comment: I'll try both approaches and see what the performance differences are.  If there is not a huge performance benefit with embedding I'll go with what you suggest. Thanks.

Comment: When you try your approach,  ensure your document size will increase incremently.

Comment: It depends on what kind of updates you're making. If these updates grow your document (array push or similar), then yes, you will have some fragmentation. In-place updates ($inc) don't cause document to be moved (no fragmentation).

By the way, it's not fragmentation per se, but rather some wasted space. That is, if document is moved to a new location, its old location won't be reused.  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11447154/data-fragmentation-in-mongo-collection